# In cellForItemAt collection view is not updating indexPath by collectionView.reloadData() in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reload, indexpath

I actually want to create table with rows and columns and doing this using UICollectionView. Problem is with reloading or updating collectionView to add or delete rows in my table. Columns and hardcoded i-e 4.

This is how i am doing;

- Creating CollectionView from storyboard
- After loading page. Hitting route to get data
- After fetching data save the fetched data in an array object.
- Update collection view with the size of the array by collectionView.reloadData().

Starting here.
Referring collection view from storyboard to my viewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

then in "viewDidLoad".

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Now after getting response from server. I am updating my Array from which i get number of rows to create. After that This is how i am reloading collectionView.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            print("size of the array is(self.portfolioHandler.data.count)")
    }
```

In my numberOfSections function. i am getting correct number of cells to create. returning as well.

```
   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    var toReturn : Int = 1
    if (self.portfolioHandler != nil) {
        let data : [PortfolioData] = self.portfolioHandler.data!
        print("dataCount : \(data.count)")
        toReturn = data.count + 1
        print("toReturn : \(toReturn)")
    }
    return toReturn
}
```

With logs i am getting the returned number. it is correct and returning data correctly.

Now in my cellForItem At index function. IndexPath is not updating. it is still 1. the top header i am creating. No Cell beneath it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    print("section: \(indexPath.section) && row: \(indexPath.row)")
```

After everything i tried. Nothing helps me to get the correct cells to create in my collectionView.

A trick can work. Only if i give hardcoded value in numberOfSections in start. Then after server response and reloading collectionView it will create those number of cells like 3 or 4 what i hardcoded above. No more then that.

But i have to create number of cells which i get from server. Dynamic.

I have spent much time on it. Please help me where i am wrong. or how i can resolve this.

Comment: Just a thought you don't really need to make a collection view to have columns.  If I have columns I just make a table view cell with multiple labels and/or images.  Can't think of a reason a collection view would be necessary for that

Comment: In collectionView you can make cell for which you can make custom background of titles. and other cell for bottom value.

Also i want to make first row and column non movable. and other rows and columns scrollable beneath them. So i prefer collection view.

Comment: I want a solution. That y is this collectionView.reloadData() function not updating IndexPath. when my dataArray is updated. the number of cells returning from numberOfSections function is correct. Why is this not updating.

Where i am wrong. i need to know. i may have to use collectionview some other day. so i want to find my mistake. Thanks @Delimiter

Comment: If indexPath is one, that means `data.count` equals zero. Did you try using breakpoints to inspect the state of your `portfolioHandler` and `portfolioHandler.data` objects?

Comment: Thanks @ɯɐɹʞ for getting me.
I didn't get you about data.count. data is my array and i want to make columns about the number of array i get from server.
And yes i using breakpoints and debugging portfolioHandler and everything from server works perfectly.

Comment: I thinks collectionView just creates first time given number of rows. To update it. it is getting old IndexPath.

Comment: do you have a breakpoint at the assignment `toReturn = data.count + 1`?

Comment: yes. Its returning correct value. what i need.
+1 is because 1st row is for label or title of that table column.

Comment: where are you calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`?

Comment: here is the discussion on Apple's Developer site: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems#discussion

Comment: Thanks @ɯɐɹʞ
But collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths) is giving me this error.

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all attempts. I am unable to solve this reload issue of collection view.

But I handle this in my app by this trick

collection view first time make cells correctly. problem is with reloading. So i made my server request in previous View Controller before coming to this View Controller. And sending the response to this View Controller. This way. i have number of cells to made. So it worked.

But as a learner i am looking forward for an answer and real solution to this reload issue problem.

I will appreciate that. Although thanks @ɯɐɹʞ for your comments.